# Variance of the sum of several random variables

Tags: random-variables, variance

I am trying to work out the variance of a sum of two sets of random variables $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\cdots,Y_m$ for a paper I'm working on. The variables $X_i$ are pairwise independent and also independent from the $Y_i's$. The variables $Y_i$ are not independent.

The solution I derived for the general case is this. First, let $C=\{X_1,\cdots,X_n,Y_1,\cdots,Y_m\}$.
$$
\begin{align*}
Var\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} C_i \right]
    &= \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} Var[C_i] + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n+m}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+m} Cov(C_i,C_j) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} Var[X_i]
       + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+m} Cov(X_i,C_j)
       + \sum_{j=1}^{m} Var[Y_j]
       + 2\sum_{i=m}^{n+m}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+m} Cov(Y_i,C_j) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} Var[X_i] + \sum_{j=1}^{m} Var[Y_j]
       + 2\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=i+1}^{m} Cov(Y_i,Y_j) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} Var[X_i] + Var\left[ \sum_{j=1}^m Y_j \right]
\end{align*}
$$

(corrections are appreciated). N.B.: the first equality can be found in the book "*Probability and Computing*" by *Michael Mitzenmacher* and *Eli Upfal* -- Cambridge University Press, 2005, in particular in exercise 3.14.

As long as the derivation above is correct, my  questions are:

- Is it necessary to put this in the paper (given that there are length restrictions)?
- Is this some sort of trivial (or straightforward) result that need not be stated? (restrictions might drop, so I need to know whether this is "well-known" or not).
- In case it is not well-known, can this be found somewhere (papers/books) which I can cite so that I don't have to write it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat trivial, if you write $ S_X = X_1 + \cdots X_n $ and $S_Y = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_m$ then by your assumptions $S_X, S_Y$ are independent random variables and thus $Var(S_X+S_Y) = Var(S_X) + Var(S_Y)$.  Then, since the X's are independent you have $Var(S_X) = Var(X_1) + \cdots + Var(X_n)$ and similarly for $S_Y$. QED.

Comment: The 'QED' made it much better. Thank you, I always make things more complicated than they are.